# Agora. How can I listen for an user joining or leaving a Video Call Agora

Tags: flutter, agora.io, videocall, agora-implementation

I am making a **Flutter app**lication using **Agora**.

The app has the ability to make a **video call** through Agora. To connect to Video Call, **rtcToken**, **appId** and **ChannelName** are used from the console of Agora **from the server** (Generate comes from the server.). For now, 2 users can make a video call with each other through these 3 fields.

**Question**: is it possible to know the **users who joined and left videoCall without sending a request** to our server from mobile?

**If this is not possible**, then how can I tell the server from the mobile that users have joined or left?

Of course, it can be done via **Rest api** or **socket**. but the request to the Rest API may not go through (For example, the phone may be turned off). I wonder if the socket will hurt the server. It would be nice to have other solutions.

### **Thanks a lot** for the answer

- 
- 
- 
- 

**How did I solve the problem?**

Agora itself could not solve the problem. Had to use web-socket. To know if the user is in the channel:

```
client.sessionController.value.isInChannel
```

This is what I used in web-socket.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**check this agora documentation.**
it shows channel methods for joining and leaving channel by the user.
https://api-ref.agora.io/en/video-sdk/flutter/6.x/API/rtc_api_overview_ng.html

[image: here is the methods]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so Agora itself can't tell our server about it. right?